# How to migrate application source code from SVN to AWS CodeCommit

Tags: ios, svn, aws-codecommit

I want to migrate iOS application source code from SVN to AWS CodeCommit.

I checked everywhere but haven't got proper information. Somewhere I got know that first need to migrate source code from SVN to GIT and then can able to migrate it on AWS Code Commit from GIT.

Need to confirm that is it correct information.

Answer (score 1):

I just did it for my project via these steps.

Migrate project from svn to git using [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git)

Create an online project in a git repository for temporarily storing the project before moving to CodeCommit. I used gitlab.

Push the git project to the online repo

```
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:corridor/project_name.git
git push origin --mirror
```

Follow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-migrate-repository-existing.html to migrate git project from gitlab to CodeCommit

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. AWS CodeCommit stores private Git repositories, and does not support SVN natively. Once you have a Git repository, you should be able to push to CodeCommit.

Also, maybe this doc can help you with the migration: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git